# Mostrar gif cargando php

Tags: php, pdo

Necesito poner un mensaje de cargando mientras una sentencia de sql se ejecuta, dado que la sentencia en concreto va a tardar un rato en realizarse y me gustaría que se mostrase un gif o un simple mensaje. Os adjunto mi codigo PHP

```
try{
    include ('./pdo.php');

    $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into datos values(:codigo,:anio,:mes,:precip,:temp,:tempMax,:tempMin)"); 
    $consulta->bindValue(':codigo',$codigo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':anio',$anio,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':mes',$mes,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':precip',$precip,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':temp',$temp,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':tempMax',$tempMax,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':tempMin',$tempMin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $resultado = $consulta->execute();  


}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error:'.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Error getFile:'.$e->getFile()."\n";
}
```

Este código esta dentro de un bucle y si son muchos registros los que tiene que insertar tarda un buen rato.
Muchas gracias de antemano a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más rápido y sencillo que podés hacer, es usar un Ajax en el HTML que muestre un GIF mientras la petición asíncrona no haya terminado, y cuando se genere la condición "success", muestre el contenido tal. Dado que PHP sólo ejecuta código del lado del servidor, no del lado del cliente (tal como lo hace JavaScript).

Te dejo un ejemplo.

Código HTML + Ajax (JQuery):

```
<div class="contenido"></div>

<script>
    var url = "archivo.php";
    var data = { variable : "valor" };
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".contenido").html("<img src='img/imagen.gif'>");
        },
        success: function(r) {
            $(".contenido").html(r);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Obviamente, es un ejemplo al aire lo que te doy. Vos modificalo a tu gusto y necesidad. Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: muchas gracis, justo lo que necesitaba.